# comparing two integers using IF statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, min

hi i'm trying to solve a practice problem using if statement, finding the minimum between two integers. the instructions are

1. Declare a variable where you want to store the minimum (say 'min')
2. Declare two variables, ask a user to input two integers and save them into those variables
3. assume that first integer is a minimum and save it to a 'min'variable declared in step 1
4. write an if-statement that compares these two values and updates the variable from step1 (there won't be any 'else' if you do it correctly)

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int mins,a,b;
cout << "Enter two integers: ";
cin >> a >> b;
mins = a;
if (a<b)
    {
    cout << "The minimum of the two is " << mins;
    }
else

return 0;
```

the programs jumps to the end if the first integer is higher than the second, my problem is that it doesn't update the 'mins'. thanks in advance

Comment: if (a<b)
    {
    cout << "The minimum of the two is " << mins;
    
else { mins = b; cout << "The minimum of the two is " << mins; }

Comment: You wrote `mins = a;` but that is not always correct. You already have cases for the situations. Just assign `mins` the right value in the right case.

Comment: You're missing content for the `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your program logic is wrong. You want this instead:

```
int main()
{
  int mins, a, b;
  cout << "Enter two integers: ";
  cin >> a >> b;

  if (a < b)
    mins = a;
  else
    mins = b;

  cout << "The minimum of the two is " << mins << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Now this is still not entirely correct because the output is incorrect if `a` and `b` are equal.

The correction is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I recommend appending a newline or `endl` to the final `cout`, to flush the buffers. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Why? The destructor of `std::cout` already does that.

Comment: @nwp Maybe because SamD will be happy to see message flushed to the output stream before an unexpected program termination.

Comment: @nwp -- because, formally, a line of text written to an output device must end with a newline character. It is **not** guaranteed to be displayed if it doesn't.

Comment: @PeteBecker It says [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init) that `std::cout` gets flushed unconditionally upon destruction. Do you have a reference claiming otherwise?

Comment: @nwp -- I didn't say it doesn't get flushed. But for the underlying issue, see the C11 standard, 7.21.2/2: "Data read in from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream only if: ... the last character is a new-line character."

Answer (score 0):

> **write an if-statement** that compares these two values and updates the
>   variable from step1 (**there won't be any 'else' if you do it
>   correctly**)

I think what you need is the following.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int min;                   // Step 1
    int a, b;                  // Step 2

    cout << "Enter two integers: ";

    cin >> a >> b;

    min = a;                   // Step 3
    if ( b < a ) min = b;      // Step 4

    cout << "The minimum of the two is " << min << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter two integers: 3 2
The minimum of the two is 2
```

So among the presented code in the answers it is only my code that does it correctly.:)

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong

```
mins = a;
if (a<b)
{
cout << "The minimum of the two is " << mins;
}
else
```

It should be.

```
if (a < b){
  mins = a;
}
else{
  mins = b;
}
cout << "The minimum of the two is " << mins;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortland if/else:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    std::cout << "Enter a and b: ";
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    int min = (a>b) ? b : a;
    std::cout << "The min element is: " << min;
}
```